# Can you identify this story involving apple of wisdom

Tags: identification-request

I have read this story a long time ago. I remember some fragments like this:

There is a young man travelling (maybe on a train). He starts talking to another passenger in the same seat (or cabin). The other passenger has an apple. The young man wants the apple but the stranger warns him that this is an apple of wisdom. After eating it he will know about everyone's feelings and intentions. The young man insists and the stranger gives him the apple before the young man gets off the train. After eating the apple, the young man is shocked. He suddenly starts "seeing" how other people like his lover/wife and other relations are not good to him.

For a long time (around 1990), I thought that this is an "Oscar Wilde" story. But after all the time I am not able to find it in any Oscar Wilde collection (the ones I came across). Also, it was in English.

If you can help me figure this out, I would like to read it again.

Comment: Wow, such a nice community. Downvote in 10 mins!

Comment: Don't take it personally; some users here dislike all [story-id] questions and downvote them habitually. Check out some of the tips [here](https://literature.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info) to see if there's any info that you remember but didn't think of when you asked the question; specifically, how long ago is "a long time ago"? You said Oscar Wilde, so it was probably English. Where did you read this?

Comment: @Shokhet thanks for your advice. I am active on stackoverflow since beta and don't worry about down-vote. But not telling what is wrong annoys a bit. Yes, some of the further information I can provide.

Comment: Okay. Good luck! I hope you find the work that you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking of putting it on English language but saw another question tagged `story-identification` and put it here!

Comment: This has some similarities to the H. G. Wells story, "The Apple." A man on a train is given the apple from the Tree of Knowledge in the Garden of Eden, but I think he throws it out the window rather than eating it.

Comment: Oh dear....@Literalman. Yes indeed, that is the story. I think my mind filled in the other details.